# Can we use tdqm progress bar with t-sne functions?

Tags: python, tqdm

I am running a program to reduce the dimension of MNIST Data from 784-dim to 2-dim using t-sne.

The program takes a very long time to finish, and I want to keep track of progress using tqdm progress bar.

I want to know how to add tqdm progress bar with t-sne function.
tqdm is working fine with loops.

I do not know how to use it for function.

```py
# TSNE
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

# Picking the top 1000 points as TSNE takes a lot of time for 15K points
data_1000 = standardized_data[0:30000,:]
labels_1000 = labels[0:30000]

# configuring the parameteres
# the number of components = 2
# default perplexity = 30
# default learning rate = 200
# default Maximum number of iterations for the optimization = 1000
model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, perplexity=200,n_iter=5000)

# I want to keep track of progress for function 
tsne_data = model.fit_transform(data_1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to notify `tqdm` about the progress. In your case, `TSNE` is an external function and all iteration is done in `TSNE`. Unless you go and change the `TSNE` code to notify `tqdm`, there is no way to use `tqdm` for this process.